# How to select database MySQL when use array compare with array?

Tags: php, mysql

How to select database MySQL when use array compare with array ?

```
$num = array("1","6","20");
```

TABLE : test_db

```
 ___________________________
| id |       number         |
| 1  | "1","2","3","4","5"  |
| 2  | "7","8","9"          |
| 3  | "10","20","30"       |
| 4  | "6","8","20"         |
```

I want to select data from table: `test_db` like

```
select * From test_db WHERE find_in_set($num, number)......
```

After finished I will get result id `1` , `3` AND `4`

Because in id 1 have `"1"`
and in id 3 have `"20"`
and in id 4 have `"6"` and `"20"`

How can I select from database.

THANK YOU.

Comment: What is the data type of "number" in your test_db tabel?

Comment: --- teo ---- column number type text

Comment: `find_in_set` can be used search only one string not an array. You can use the input array values to generate dynamic query for achieving it.

Comment: Learn about *database normalization*. This is exactly the reason why you do *not* store "an array" in a single column. You should have a one-to-many relationship between two tables here.

Answer (score 0):

Your DB schema is pretty bad and in addition you are saving comma-separated values using double quote. You should normalize the table and make it one to many relation. However in the current case you need to generate the query dynamically since  `find_in_set` could be used to search only one value from a set. Here is a way you can try

```
$num = array("1","6","20");

$qry = "select * from test_db";
$i = 1 ;
if(is_array($num) && count($num) > 0 ){
    $qry .= " where ";
    foreach($num as $num){
        if($i == 1 ){
            $qry .= " find_in_set(".$num.",replace(number,'\"','') ) ";
        }else{
            $qry .= " OR find_in_set(".$num.",replace(number,'\"','') ) ";
        }
        $i++;
    }
}


// Finally execute the query in variable $qry
```

Comment: thankyou i will test , and i will back to tell you what happen.